# How to provide a hyperlinks to each of the database entity

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

i have a table in the database consists of three columns and 4 rows. And now i want to set hyperlink for each of the entity present in the 3rd column of the table in the database and display the output.

i tried printing the values of array as

```
echo "<td>", $row['a'], "</td><td>", $row['b'] ,"</td><td>", "<a href=\"http://foo/foo/".$row['link']."\">"."view"."</a>","</td>" ;?>
```

where a,b and link are the column name of 1,2 and 3 respectively. and i want to hyperlink the html pages. How can i do it? when i try to run my code, its goes to the folder `http://foo/foo/`

Comment: Maybe because you set an hyperlink to `http://foo/foo` ? `<a href=\"http://foo/foo/".$row['link']."\">"`

Comment: You're concatenating with `,` instead of `.`

Comment: how are you doing the query to the db and the fetch operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `echo` part and just output as HTML. This way you don't have to worry about all that messy concatenation (you're using `,` instead of `.`, which *is* valid, but in this context is unnecessary).

```
<?php

// code here

?>

<td><?= $row['a'] ?></td><td><?= $row['b'] ?></td><td><a href="http://foo/foo/<?= $row['link'] ?>">view</a></td>

<?php

// more code here
.
.
.
```

Comment: using `echo` instead of `<?=` is a better practice `<?php echo $row['a'] ?>` etc..

Comment: @Gustonez Since when? Oh, right because "some" servers don't have `short_open_tags` turned on. Any developer worth his salt knows how to get a host to turn that option on, so your argument is moot.

Comment: @Gustonez Your argument is showing me how short open tags work?

Comment: @Gustonez BTW, as your documentation notes, *"Since PHP 5.4.0, <?= is always available."* Which means that the guys who *maintain* PHP seem to think it's a useful construct.

Comment: of course not (i am not showing YOU). but only to let junior coders use standard ways to script.

Comment: @Gustonez it seems to me that by making `<?=` available as a *standard feature of PHP*, that `<?=` *is* the standard way to script within HTML (since it's simply shorthand for `<?php echo`).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15722/discussion-between-gustonez-and-matt)

Comment: @Gustonez I can't. My office blocks that feature. Let's just agree that it's a matter of *preference* at this point.